# Angular HttpClient.put observable returning null

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable

I subscribe to the `Observable` returned by my `HttpClient.put(...)`, the response comes back `null`. Here's my code:

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};

updateIsEnabled(type: string, isChecked: boolean) {
    const url = `${this.isEnabledUrl}?type=${type}&isEnabled=${isChecked}`;

    this.http.put(url, this.httpOptions)
        .pipe(
          catchError(this.handleError('updateIsEnabled'))
    ).subscribe(response => {
        if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
            //do something
        }
    });
}
```

But I get:
**`ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'getStatusCode' of null`**

I am sure that I'm responding with a `200 OK` (`Spring` backend), but with an empty body. I figured maybe it was expecting a `JSON`. So I changed the options to:

```
httpTextOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'text/plain', 
                           'Content-Length': '0'})
}
```

But still with the same results.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: observe response

Comment: Even if you did follow [the docs](https://angular.io/guide/http) to get an observable of the response rather than the parsed body, [`HttpResponse`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpResponse) has no such method. Why did you think this would work?

Comment: @jonrsharpe that is besides the point. Would you have brought it up if I wrote `response.abcdefg()`?

Comment: I'd have the same question, certainly.

Comment: Besides jonrsharpe's question, which I agree on... have you **checked** the network tab to see what you are receiving? Seems there is no value in the response, like the error suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get the point of catchError as it destroys the observable, not sure if it is a bug or I don't understand it properly but I have learned not to use it as it isn't useful for catching errors.

```js
const { throwError } = rxjs;
const { catchError } = rxjs.operators;

throwError('error').pipe(
  catchError(e => { console.log(e); })
).subscribe(val => { console.log(val); }, e => { console.log(e); });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.3/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

You can get the error with a tap and an error handler that doesn't destroy the observable

```js
const { throwError } = rxjs;
const { tap } = rxjs.operators;

throwError('error').pipe(
  tap(undefined, e => { console.log(e); })
).subscribe(val => { console.log(val); }, e => { console.log(e); });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.3/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```